# What is the "ActionStatus" in an App Indexing API Action

Tags: android, firebase

I am working on implementing App Indexing into my app, and I've come across this basic code to `getAction()` in various samples and docs:

```
public Action getAction() {
    Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
        .setName(mTitle)
        .setDescription(mDescription)
        .setUrl(mUrl)
        .build();

    return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
        .setObject(object)
        .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
        .build();
}
```

What I can't find anywhere is how to know when to use `Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED` vs `Action.STATUS_TYPE_ACTIVE` or even `Action.STATUS_TYPE_FAILED`. I can find nothing that explains what "ActionStatus" is in the context of an App Indexing "Action."

Can anyone tell me the meaning of ActionStatus, and in which circumstance you'd use either status?